# a question related to state maintenance

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new to Objective-C. I know how to save values using `NSUserDefaults` when the user presses the home button but it affects my application's performance. I want one method that saves values without affecting my application's performance.

Comment: The question is a bit strange.. And not specific. Why does saving values to user defaults affects performance? If you don't save it with timer, it should not...

Comment: What are you trying to put in the user defaults that is making your app so slow?

Comment: Seeing as you're specifically concerned about your application's performance, I'm assuming you've profiled your code. What were the results? What are your specific concerns?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [DTResurrectionKit](https://bitbucket.org/danielctull/dtresurrectionkit) which is a handy way to store state.